# How do I remove Cisco Anyconnect from the Dock?

Tags: macos, dock, customization

I am unable to remove Anyconnect from dock. It persists like Finder. On checking `~/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` I don't find Anyconnect listed in it. Is this setting stored somewhere else from where I can remove?

I am using Mavericks.

Comment: What shows when you right-click it?

Comment: Do you want to remove Anyconnect completely? Or just from the Dock? Can you move Anyconnect within the Dock? Is Anyconnect still running? Background process or similar?

Comment: Well I am an idiot, Didn't realize that anyconnect was running when I removed it.

Comment: Feel free to write your answer as a proper answer rather than editing your question.

Comment: Is it possible to remove it when running? It already has an icon in my tray like dropbox and docker but those app dont need to be hanging there all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you quit a program and then drag the dock icon out of the dock if it remains. The dragging needs to be a few inches outside the dock and pause until you see the cloud animation arrive around the icon before releasing the mouse.

Answer (score -1):

Usual method of dragging and dropping app out of Dock works. I didn't realize that, the app was already running.